# Get all records from one table that are not in either column of a second table

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, rails-activerecord

I have a **Player** model and a **Match** model. Each **Match** has a winner_id and a loser_id for the winning and losing **Player**.

**How can I get all players that have never been in a match?**

I.e. get all player ids, that are in neither the winner_id nor the loser_id column.

I'm using Rails 4.

```
Players
-------------
id    
1 
2
3
4
5
6
7

Matches
-------------
winner_id     loser_id
1             2
1             3
1             4
```

So the result should be players 5, 6, and 7.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Player.where.not(id: Match.pluck(:winner_id,:loser_id).flatten.uniq)

Answer (score 0):

There might be some better way also. but you can do it like this also:

```
ids = Matche.select(:winner_id).distinct.map{|match| match.winner_id} + Matche.select(:loser_id).distinct.map{|match| match.loser_id}
@players = Player.where.not(id: ids)
```

Comment: `Match.select(:winner_id).distinct.to_a` returns `[#<Match id: nil, winner_id: 1>, #<Match id: nil, winner_id: 2>], ...`. 

So this answer doesn't work

Comment: I have made changes in my answer that will work for you